# How to override 802.1p CoS on outgoing interfaces?

Tags: qos, juniper-junos

In Cisco, this can be easily achieved by:

```
policy-map TVPrio
 description Set VLAN priority to 4
 class class-default
  set cos 4
```

and apply this policy-map to the interface. How to do equivalent in JunOS?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for reminding. I always accept the answer which is working. However, as I replied in each answers, they does not work for my question, thus I didn't mark any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set all forwarding-classes to the same code-point:

```
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class assured-forwarding loss-priority low code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class assured-forwarding loss-priority high code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class expedited-forwarding loss-priority high code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class expedited-forwarding loss-priority low code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class network-control loss-priority low code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class network-control loss-priority high code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class best-effort loss-priority high code-point 100
set class-of-service rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4 forwarding-class best-effort loss-priority low code-point 100
```

Then apply this to the interface(s) you want to change the CoS bits:

```
set class-of-service interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 rewrite-rules ieee-802.1 all-to-cos-4
```

Mind you that this is only for the default forwarding-classes. If you have defined your own forwarding-classes you have to do it for these as well.

Comment: The rewrite-rules only works for forwarded traffic, not for routing engine generated traffic, for example, the DHCP request.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party on this one, but to override RE-generated CoS values, you can use:

```
set class-of-service host-outbound-traffic forwarding-class <FORWARDING-CLASS>
```

Then set your re-write rules for that forwarding-class appropriately.

If you are happy with just DSCP markings, you can assign these statically using:

```
set class-of-service host-outbound-traffic dscp-code-point <DSCP-CODEPOINT>
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, this method does work for DSCP override, but it overrides all traffic sent from RE. And I only need to override RE traffic from one single interface, not all of them...